# C# Why do I only get partial results when parsing out a CSV or TSV file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csv, split, generic-list

I am trying to get the second value from a CSV file with 100 rows.  I am getting the first 42 values then it stops... no error messege, or error handling at all for that matter.  I am perplexed and am on a timeline.  It is also doing it for a TSV file, but giving the first 43 results.  Please help and let me know if it looks strange to you.

I am using streamreader, reading each line into a string array, splitting the array and taking the second value and adding it to a list...

```
        string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        List<string> stkno = new List<string>();

        foreach (var line in path)
        {
            string s = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] words = s.Split(',');
            stkno.Add(words[1]);
        }
        var message = string.Join(",", stkno.ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: No exceptions? What if you step through the loop?

Comment: @Dave_P - Please do yourself a favor and DO NOT use that string to get a path to your file.  Please simply get the current user's desktop path and work from there.  You could also consider placing the file localy to the application itself.

Comment: why would you give me a -1 on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `path` variable is a string. That means when you `foreach` over it, you're getting a sequence of *characters* - 'C' then ':' then '\' etc. I don't think that's what you mean to do...

Here's a simpler approach using [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";

List<string> stkno = (from line in File.ReadLines(path)
                      let words = line.Split(',')
                      select words[1]).ToList();
```

Or:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";

List<string> stkno = File.ReadLines(path)
                         .Select(line => line.Split(',')[1])
                         .ToList();
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 and you don't mind reading the whole file in one go, you can use `File.ReadAllLines` instead.

Comment: actually, it was reading the lines from the file...  it just stopped at 42%.  Matt Manela fixed me up though, thanks.

Comment: @Dave_P: You were reading lines from the file, but only while there were more characters *in the path* - that was determining the number of lines you read. I believe my approach of iterating over the lines is cleaner than using StreamReader explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You are accidentally iterating over the number of characters in the file path instead of the number of lines in the string. This change should fix that:

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    List<string> stkno = new List<string>();

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] words = s.Split(',');
        stkno.Add(words[1]);
    }
    var message = string.Join(",", stkno.ToArray());
    MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: You rock.  Thanks for your help.  I tried using peek at one point but maybe I didnt rebuild the solution first before hand.  Problem solved.  It is nice to be in the company of geniuses.

Comment: Personally I don't like using Peek like this - it's cleaner to call ReadLine and see if it returns null, IMO. Also note that there's no `using` statement here - the StreamReader will never be closed. (Another advantage of using `File.ReadLines` in conjunction with foreach... no explicit cleanup required.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I completely agree with you and would recommend implementing it the way you showed. I was just trying to keep the poster's code the similar.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";
    var secondWords = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                        let words = line.Split(',')
                        select words[1];

    var message = string.Join(",", secondWords.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to do:

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\dave\Desktop\codes\testfile.txt";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    List<string> stkno = new List<string>();

    string s;
    while(s = sr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        string[] words = s.Split(',');
        stkno.Add(words[1]);
    }
    var message = string.Join(",", stkno.ToArray());
    MessageBox.Show(message);
```